# MatLab - Euclidean Distance Plot 3D

Tags: matlab, euclidean-distance

Im new in matlab programming and I have small issue.

I want to draw a plot 3d of Euclidean distance function for 2 coordinates, like in this picture below:

[image: pic]

Could you help me with the source code? How I can draw this plot?
My first thoughts was wrong:

```
[A] = meshgrid(-100:.5:100, -100:.5:100);   
D1 = bwdist(A);
figure
surf(double(A), double(D1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is done like this...

```
[x, y] = meshgrid(-100:.5:100, -100:.5:100);
```

The you have to calculated the euclidean distances. I assume you want them with the origin.

```
z = (x.^2 + y.^2).^0.5;   % square root of sum of squares (euclidean distance with origin)
surf(x, y, z);
```

NOTE: meshgrid(-100:.5:100, -100:.5:100) might make the resolution of the plot too high. If you have trouble viewing the plot, reduce the resolution.

Use `[x, y] = meshgrid(-100:5:100, -100:5:100);`