# Display 3D Matrix using pyqtgraph

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

I am trying to display a 3D matrix (distance matrix) using python programming and pyqtgraph (the plot is similar to this example in Matlab: [MatLab - Euclidean Distance Plot 3D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20839329/matlab-euclidean-distance-plot-3d).)

I have the list of points that I want to display on plot as x and y coordinates and the distance is already calculated and I have the related matrix.
I have tried the examples related to Mesh and Surface Plot from the  pyqtgraph.examples but the final plot is not what I am looking for.

I am new to pyqtgraph. Can you help me with the method and the parameters that I can use for drawing this plot?

EDIT: I have tried several codes and examples so far . In the following code I used this example https://gist.github.com/markjay4k/da2f55e28514be7160a7c5fbf95bd243 for the grids and Surface plot form pyqtgraph.examples but it doesn't show the plot. I am not sure if I should use Mesh or Surface plot.

```
w = gl.GLViewWidget()
w.opts['distance'] = 40
w.setWindowTitle('graph')
w.setGeometry(0, 110, 1920, 1080)
w.show()
gx = gl.GLGridItem()
gx.rotate(90, 0, 1, 0)
gx.translate(-10, 0, 0)
w.addItem(gx)
gy = gl.GLGridItem()
gy.rotate(90, 1, 0, 0)
gy.translate(0, -10, 0)
w.addItem(gy)
gz = gl.GLGridItem()
gz.translate(0, 0, -10)
w.addItem(gz)

x1 = [0,1,2,3]
y1 = [0,1,2,3]
x1=np.array(x1)
y1=np.array(y1)
z1 = [[22,33,44,55],[44,55,66,77],[11,22,33,44],[66,44,99,89]]
z1=np.matrix(z1)
p2 = gl.GLSurfacePlotItem(x=x1, y=y1, z=z1,shader='normalColor')
p2.translate(-10,-10,0)
w.addItem(p2)
```

Comment: Can you add your code so we can see where the error might be?

Comment: @Nathan I added the code that I have tried so far.

Comment: What problems do you have ?, I tested the link code and it runs correctly.